# Spring data redis sort/order by

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-framework-beans

I'm currently working on a project which require redis as its main repository for caching data, using references from [spring-data-redis-example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples)

i'm also require to do things like get and sort the list retrieved from redis, to achieve such cases, what i have tried is like below :

> PageRequest.of(1, 10, Sort.Direction.ASC, "rank")

and

> findBySomeAndThingOrderByRankAsc

but none of the above seem to resolve my issue to be able to sort the data retrieved from redis

here is my redis configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.db.redis.repository")
public class RedisConfiguration {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName(Properties.getString("redis.hostname"));
        redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(Integer.parseInt(Properties.getString("redis.port")));

        return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisTemplate strRedisTemplate() {
        StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

and here is the pojo

```
@RedisHash("somehash")
public class SortOnRedisExample implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -895893308381522209L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String some;
    @Indexed
    private String thing;
    @Indexed
    private Integer rank;

    public SortOnRedisExample() {}

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(Integer rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getSome() {
        return some;
    }

    public void setSome(String some) {
        this.some = some;
    }

    public String getThing() {
        return thing;
    }

    public void setThing(String thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }
}
```

my question is, is sort/order by supported by `spring-data-redis` in jpa style? if not, what is the alternative to do so?

any pointer would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you find a solution for this issue? I have same problem here.

Comment: yes, you can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635337/spring-redis-sort-keys, helps me a lot to find a pointer and alternative solution

Comment: Thank you. Your link just show how to sorting but I want to sorting and filtering by field just like your method findBySomeAndThingOrderByRankAsc above. How can you do that?

Comment: Hi there! i think i've mistaken my own question, my requirement only needed to sort out some specific field without the need to filter anything. i use another platform to do these filtering things, you'r welcome btw!